# excel drop down disabled selections

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I multiple dependent excel drop-down menus. for Example

```
** Price Range **
1
2
3
4

**colors**
red
blue
green
yellow

**things**
car
TV
house
glass
```

etc etc. 
This would be the ideal setup:

Lets say from colors you choose red from the colors drop down menu, then i want only car and TV to be selectable under the things drop down menu. But if you choose blue in the 'colors' drop down, everything is selectable under 'things' drop down.

Is there a way this can be completed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a named range under the names of the colors and list only the items you want to show in them. You then set the data validation to the cell with the first drop down so it uses that named range.

Comment: So what if the list that you want to base the exceptions on start with numbers, when defining names you cannot have  defined names start with numbers or special characters characters.

Comment: Maybe make a helper column or columns that are hidden and converts to another name and then use that?